# Redirect all pages to holding page - Azure Website

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, azure, iis-7.5, webmatrix

I've built a custom holding page for my site when I take it down for maintenance.

I know how to change the default page to use the new page, but how do I redirect ALL pages to it temporarily? (ie, www.mysite.com/page1).

My site is hosted in Azure as a Basic website. My site is written in ASP.NET Web Pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an *App_Offline.htm* file when you take your site offline for maintenance. If you add a file with that name to the root of your Web Pages site, the site will be unloaded by IIS and the content of the page displayed instead. As soon as you remove the file (or change its name), the site will be restarted.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/426755

Answer (score -1):

If you use a .htaccess file you may add this to the file

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourwebsite.com/TheMainenancePage.html [R=301]
```

Hope this helps :)